# How do I access the string name of the parent class from a class method in a extended class or included module

Tags: ruby, class, module, object, oop

My problem basically looks like this:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.who
      self.class.to_s
    end
  end
end

class World < Foo::Bar

end
```

When I call `World.who` I don't get `"World"` as a result, I get `"Class"`. Some quick Googling didn't yield anything useful, so hence I'm here hoping someone will know how to get the correct class name :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're calling `foo.bar` then inside the `bar` method the value of `self` will be `foo`. So when you call `World.who` the value of `self` inside `who` is `World`. Since `World` is a class, `World.class` will return `Class`, so that's what you get.

To get back `"World"` just call `self.to_s` or `self.name` (or just `to_s` or `name`).

Answer (score 2):

You get that because `World` is a `Class`. In ruby, `AClass.class != AClass`. So, you could use this:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.who
      to_s
    end
  end
end

class World < Foo::Bar

end
```